# Extracting equations from a word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The difference of two integers is $18$. One integer is one-third of the other integer. What are the integers?

I know that the first equation is $x-y=18$, after that..was confused.

Answer (score 2):

$$x-y=18\\
\text{And }x=\dfrac{y}{3}\text{ OR }y=\dfrac{x}{3}\\
\implies \dfrac{y}{3}-y=18\text{ OR }x-\dfrac{x}{3}=18\\
\implies y=-27,x=-9\text{ OR }x=27,y=9$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the 1st number is one-third the 2nd.Then $y = 3x$. So $x - 3x = 18$. So $-2x = 18$, and $x = -9$, and $y = 3*(-9) = -27$